# How can Monstera plant know which leaves to split?

Tags: botany

The monstera plant splits some leaves when they put shadow on other leaves behind it, if I understand correctly. But how can the plant know which leave is responsible for the shadowing and therefore which leave to split? Are there other phaenomena similar to this in other plants?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a case of mature leaves always splitting and younger leaves always growing from the bottom? Because you may be mistaking *why* it splits for *how* it splits. Many photos show leaves that are split with no obvious shadowing; Just that larger moire mature leaves split automatically.

Comment: Plants don't "know" (that I know of) anything, but they do react to many things: hormones, light, temperature, day length, injury, and myriad other factors , many of which I know nothing about. Whatever the case is with Monstera, it's a physiological reaction to some stimulus, not an intellectual one. If I had a few hours, I could give you a layperson answer based on [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/botlinnean/article/150/1/25/2420312), but I have fewer hours left than you probably do, so have at it!

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Obviously, I am looking for a mechanism, yes.